# HTML5 video tag on IOS 11

Tags: html, video, html5-video, ios11

I have working code for a video element within my site thats fully functioning on ios 9/10 and all the normal browsers (chrome/ff/ie) etc.

I've noticed that since the ios 11 update the videos no longer play or even work at all. They appear as a blank box with the controls but pressing play does nothing and opening the video full screen does nothing.

[image]

Here is my relatively simple code

```
         <video playsinline onclick="play()" controls autoplay 
         controlsList="nodownload">
           <source src="assets/images/video_im.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         </video>
```

I've tried different variations of using playsinline="true" and controls="true". They have no effect.

I've tried to google the issue but there seems to be nothing except a podcast taking about ios 11 removing html5 video support, surely there is a fix?

Any insight/help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the following code:

```html
<video>
    <source src="path/to/video.mp4">
</video>
```

stopped working on ios11 (with many other features too...). I confirm that `source` tag did work on ios9 here). Try placing the `src="path/to/video.mp4"` into the `video` tag directly, it should work on ios11.

A working example taken from [webkit.org post on New video Policies for iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/):

```html
<div id="either-gif-or-video">
  <video src="image.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline></video>
  <img src="image.gif">
</div>
```

Safari on MacOS seems to have a similar problem, maybe it's easier to test there. Looks like we lost the *multiple source* feature tho :(

Comment: Did you try with a different video format? I'm actually using `m4v`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with videos not playing on Safari. The problem was my web server. I moved the video to another hosting server, loaded it from there and it worked.

e.g.

instead of:

```
<video src='/myVideo.mp4' controls> </video>
```

do something like this:

```
<video src='https://anotherServer.com/myVideo.mp4' controls> </video>
```