# Safari HTML5 video no longer autoplays

Tags: safari, html5-video, mobile-safari

Recently I have noticed that the video elements on my site no longer autoplay on iOS Safari or desktop Safari.

The current code looks something like this:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="/path/to/poster.jpg>">
  <source src="/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

From my understanding, this is enough to abide by Webkit's new video policies for [iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) and [MacOS](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/) to allow for a video to autoplay.

I have searched for similar questions and not come across a solution. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221536/html5-video-tag-on-ios-11) it seems like the `source` tag itself could be the problem.

This [thread](https://forum.webflow.com/t/html5-video-does-not-autoplay-on-ios-anymore/54029/3) suggests that iOS blocks videos from autoplaying on low power mode as well. But I've determined this isn't causing my issue.

Has anyone come across this issue themselves? Do you have a solution? Can someone point me in the direction of some Safari change logs where this breaking change was introduced?

**Details**
iOS 11.4
MacOS Safari Version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.2)

**EDIT**

The video isn't being loaded correctly, when I check the Network panel in Safari dev tools the MP4 shows up under 'Other' with the error "An error occurred trying to load the resource".

If I try to play the video directly in Safari (eg: go to https://my-website.com/path/to/video.mp4) I get the error `Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load`

I think it's because my video is a file blob, and Safari expects videos to be from streaming servers (as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103103/failed-to-load-resource-plugin-handled-load-on-ios/26972619?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

**EDIT 2**

Might be something to do with how Safari is introducing the ability to use videos in `img` tags? See [this](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2017/animated-gif-without-the-gif/) and [this](https://webkit.org/blog/8216/new-webkit-features-in-safari-11-1/)